# Google Cloud Workflows API result with nextPageToken

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-workflows

In Cloud Workflows, I have to

call an API
this API returns a lot of results
iterate over that through the nextPageToken

I was thinking maybe to use switch/condition to do a while nextPageToken exist,

Like: the condition is result.nextPageToken (supposing that it exist)

It seems that it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well essentially you have a map and you need to check for the existence of a key.

```
 switch:
        - condition: ${not("nextPageToken" in result)}
          next: NextPageMissing
```